# Comparing string value to .json data for API test in Postman

Tags: postman, chai, assert

```
pm.test("Correct Asset Returned", 
function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData.AssetId).to.equal(pm.variables.get("AssetNumber"));});
```

I get this error. (The test should pass) :

> AssertionError: expected 315 to equal '315'**

Comment: There's a bug in Postman that's causing this: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/2190

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because the type of the `AssetNumber` variable is the `String` and the type of the `AssetId` is the `Number`. So you should convert to string or to number one of them before verify it.

```
pm.expect(`${jsonData.AssetId}`).to.equal(pm.variables.get("AssetNumber"));});
```

or

```
pm.expect(jsonData.AssetId).to.equal(Number(pm.variables.get("AssetNumber")));});
```

Comment: This is a decent workaround, but the underlying problem is that a bug in Postman that causes the variable type to get converted to String: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/2190